# Trouble with alignment using iomanip

Tags: c++

I'm not great at using the `iomanip` library and have tried looking around for similar problems, but haven't been able to implement a good solution. I'm trying to display words that are used most frequently and least frequently. My code is (abridged version showing what I'm having problems with):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    string word1 = "helloooo";
    string word2 = "hey";
    cout << "MOST FREQUENT: ";

    cout << setw(7) << left << word1;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "(" << 5 << ")" << endl;


    cout << "LEAST FREQUENT: ";
    cout << setw(9) << left << word2;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "(" << 3 << ")" << endl;
}
```

This is only a simpler version of the code I'm working on. In reality, the words will be pulled from a vector and the numbers will be different. The words should be center aligned and the right side should show the number in a column. I want it to look like:

```
MOST FREQUENT: hellooooo    (5)
LEAST FREQUENT:   hey       (3)
```

But instead I get:

```
MOST FREQUENT: helloooo    (5)
LEAST FREQUENT: hey          (3)
```

I'm just not good using `iomanip` and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you always printing only two lines? A non-scalable, and kind of easy fix would be to just count how many characters is each line and word. Then you can compute how many whitespace characters you need to write in between each word.

Comment: I am always printing only two lines, but the word will be different depending on user input in the overall code. So just counting spaces wouldn't work I don't think.

Comment: Even if the word is always different, you also always know the word before printing it. I am not recommending the counting solution, but it will work.

Comment: Okay I got it to look correctly using the current words. I added a variable ```int spaces = 3 + word1.length()```. I used ```setw(spaces)``` for ```MOST FREQUENT``` then for ```LEAST FREQUENT``` I did ```setw(spaces - word2.length() - 1)```. I made the column on the bottom ```setw(5 + word2.length())```. I'll check if it works for any word. EDIT: does not work for all words